Why does Eli accuse Daniel of lusting after women in "There Will Be Blood"?
In the movie There Will Be Blood (2007), during the baptism scene, Eli lists Daniel's sins, and the first thing he says is "you've lusted after women."
Throughout the movie, Daniel is not at all interested in women. And from my point of view, this seems to be the case in what is not seen in the movie: Daniel is not interested in women. So, how should we interpret Eli's comment? Is it just hearsay? Can we really assume that Daniel has "lusted after women"?
Another possible explanation is that, the night before, Daniel was together with his brother in what looked like a brothel. And it is possible that this reached Eli's ears within a few hours.

It's been a long time since I saw it, so just a comment: Isn't that a pretty safe guess to make about any man? Not putting all men down, but it's kind of like pretending to see into someone's past and saying, "You've engaged in schadenfreude!"

Hi Petersu, can you focus your post (by [edit]ing it) on how Eli would know such a thing, and rephrase (or remove) the question "how should we interpret Eli's comment?"? I believe that it's currently in the closing queue because through this it seems to ask for opinion, while I think you're asking why (or based on what) Eli mentions Daniel's supposed lust after women.

@Joachim, I don't think that's an improvement on the question. Answering how Eli knew this is also going to be opinion-based, don't you think? Because I doubt there are any clues in the movie to answer that as well. Besides, the real point of my question is to better understand Daniel's character.

@anongoodnurse, yes. As a man who is disgusted by what I see in male groups, I think that is a pretty safe guess.

For the question, it doesn't really matter if it can be answered by anything in the film, you can still ask for (objective) evidence of Eli's claim; there's nothing opinion-based about that.

@Petersu - Daniel was seen openly leaving a bar with a prostitute. This is not a large community and there were many people around who could have seen him and mentioned it to Eli.

In the original script Daniel has sex with a woman he's just met in a bar, an attractive prostitute. Clearly he has lust in his heart if he's seen openly consorting with harlots in a public place.

DANIEL is in a safe, dark, quiet place with the Vixen. He is on his
knees and has his head buried inside her legs, leaning her up against
a wall. HOLD.
He finishes and gives her some money.
He fixes his hair, wipes sweat from his face with a rag from his
pocket and leaves.


Yeah, but how did Eli know?

@anongoodnurse Probably heard it through the grapevine…

@anongoodnurse - If it's happening in a public place it's not at all surprising that people would gossip
